# bootstrap overidding readonly css in rails

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'ved got my application.css like this below. For some reason, all my "readonly" attributed inputs are all greyed, and I want to make it white. Im not able to do it, and I can only suspect bootstrap styles have precedence over it. Something wrong here ?

```
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require datepicker
 *= require bootstrap-switch 
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= require validationEngine.jquery 
 */

[readonly] { 
    border-color: black;
    background-color:white; 
}
```

Comment: one possible answer is to use !important, highly not recommended, any other way to troubleshoot

Comment: A couple of things to consider, make sure your CSS is being called last otherwise the bootstrap CSS will take precedence. Second make sure your form fields dont have 'disabledTextInput' which are BS out of the box disable CSS classes. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-disabled

Comment: jo Axil, did my solution work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

You are requiring `self` *before* `bootstrap`, that's why other styles will override your `readonly` style. You should change the order to:

```
 *= .
 *= .
 *= . everything else
 *= .
 *= .
 *= require_self
 */

[readonly] { 
  border-color: black;
  background-color:white; 
}
```

This way your stylings in `self` will get defined last, thus becoming the most important. No need for the `important!` property, which is bad practice